# Inactive Moderators and high rep users

Tags: discussion, moderators

Recently after Ramdan I see this site is not having much activity by some of the Moderators. One of the Mods is not even seen around, even while he was around he contributed little although earlier this year he was actively contributing quality content. Moreover there is a similar case for high rep users, So what is the reason behind this and how to increase Moderator participation?

Answer (score 6):

The truth is that there was a notable spike in traffic duing [Ramadan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan) this year.  Presumably people who are interested in learning about the sacred month turned to this site for information.  After that time period, site activity simply returned to normal levels.

This site has 4 moderators.  Normally beta sites are given three, so it doesn't hurt if one of them takes some time off for whatever reason.  Of note, this site had far fewer flags in the last quarter than did Christianity and Judaism.  The moderators are handling flags quickly and the workload does not seem onerous.

Remember that moderators, like all other participants on the site, are volunteers.  They have obligations and responsibilities outside of the site and off of the internet.  The same is true of high-reputation users who may chose to come and go as they wish.

The best way to encourage participation is to ask excellent questions.  The next best way is to provide excellent answers.  When people enjoy reading the site, they are more likely to take some time to write for it.

---

I took a closer at some of the metrics we use internally to evaluate participation in the site and there seems to be no particular problem.  Almost all the high-reputation users are visiting the site on a regular basis.  That doesn't mean they always post something, but they are reading and voting.  This adds value to the site, though it's not usually something people notice.

There is a core of users who are posting regularly.  We'd like to see that core growing.  It's not.  However, the number of regular posters has held firm for a year or so.  There's a substantially larger group who post occasionally.  This group has increased noticeably since the start of Ramadan this year.  It's still too early to know if these folks will be "hooked" on the site or, having had their questions well-answered, move on.

In any case, there's not much that worrying about it can do.

Comment: The moderators of a beta site are also builders , not just handling flags , they need to contribute by asking and answering questions setting an example of how things should work. They should also attract other high quality users to this site, Irrespective of religion.

Comment: @Islam: I updated my answer.  To be honest, I don't think you've identified a real problem.  I know from other sites that it's easy to feel the loss of a single user so strongly that it feels like the site is hurting.  The reality often is that people move onto other things and new people take their place.

Comment: Shouldn't the mods contribute in terms of more posts like quality Q\A. I think we lag in the questions\day metric Also many of the high rep users are not posting since a long time

Comment: @Islam: Moderation duties and answering duties are entirely orthogonal.  The top user on Stack Overflow has repeatedly declined to run for moderator.  He'd prefer to focus on answering questions. Some moderators are willing and able to do both, but this is not by any means a requirement.

Comment: e.g the highest rep users like Abdullah, Ansari,Ahmed Han are  not contributing by posting Q\A they may be reading it but they should also post. It would be great if you could send them Mails to contribute content here.

Comment: Thank you Jon for answering. I can't really add more to what you wrote here. I do keep an eye out for mod duties and pitch in when needed. And while I'm not as active as in the beginning, I do try to answer well-written questions.

Comment: @JonEricson this is not SO, this is a nascent community site which needs quality content in good quantity.

Comment: @Jon, I somewhat agree with owari. The quality of questions and answers are important, but so is the feedback you get for writing them. There are users on the site that are not OK with the idea that their perspective might not be the only perspective on an issue. I think some answers are down-voted for no reason other than not matching the beliefs of the voter even if it is a plausible Islamic perspectives on an issue. I think this site has a long way to go to reach a friendly atmosphere of knowledge sharing and learning from the state of preaching and judging others.

Comment: [cont.] There is also the issue from other side, i.e. the issue of how posts are written. I will pick one from a one of good users: the first line of [this question](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/) says: "As is known ..." and states something as a fact which others might not agree (I personally don't have an opinion if it is true or false, but I would guess this is not an issue where there is consensus on it by scholars).

Comment: [cont.] In short, there is too much judgments based on users' personal beliefs and too much representation of information as factual. I think the language of posts should follow the norms of Wikipedia articles. Such a factual statement when it is not clear if there is a consensus on it among would be removed from Wikipedia articles, but such statements are quite common on this site.

Comment: @Kaveh: Could you write your concerns up as a meta-question here?  Not only would it allow you more room to write up your thoughts, it will also give them more visibility.  This sounds like an important issue with the site and I'd appreciate more people being able to look into it.  Thank you!

Comment: @Kaveh: I noticed you have meta-questions: [Disagreement should not be a basis for down-voting](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/746/138) and [Try to help others improve their posts before down-voting them](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/188/138).  Do these cover your first comment?

Comment: @Jon, somewhat though the comments above are more specific. I may post something next week, I am a bit busy these days.

Answer (score -1):

My two cent here is that the atmosphere of the site is also an important point, and to me it was not good some months ago. I don't know about the current state. Some people always trying to prove why others are Mushrik, teasing the others by such attributions and etc.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the sort of thing you are talking about?  It also sounds like this might be better addressed as a separate question.  (I assume the downvotes are because this answer is about a different issue than inactive users.)