# Moderator Reappointment

Tags: discussion, moderators

As seen that some of the moderators are almost inactive and this site needs good content from people who know this model well , and its a long time since having the same mods , so what about a planned moderator reelection \ reappointment? Is re appointment possible?

Comment: Pro-tempore mods aren't elected, [they're appointed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Answer (score 5):

My answer is the same as [the last time you asked](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/802/inactive-moderators-and-high-rep-users): the diamond moderators are doing their (rather specialized) job remarkably well.  The only thing I should add is that all of the moderators have been active on the site since the last time this came up.  They might not all be posting questions or answer, but that's in no way a requirement.  We are very happy with all of them and have no plans to reappoint them.

It's important to note that [[Islam.SE] Is You](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/).  As you earn more and more of your fellow users' trust, you will have a greater responsibility to lead the site.  Moderation on Stack Exchange is *mostly* done by high-reputation users.  Appointed moderators are given a few extra powers in order to respond to flags.  But for the most part, they simply accelerate the process that any other user might follow to keep the site clean and civil.